# CentOS Error: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

I am getting this error on CentOS:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file
```

I tried to solve this problem using following command.

```
yum -y install glibc.i686
```

But it didn't work. It says:

> No package glibc.i686 available.

```
My CentOS version: 6.7
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

use the command

```
yum provides ld-linux.so.2
```

You may see something like this:

```
yum provides ld-linux.so.2
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.symnds.com
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: mirror.solarvps.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.symnds.com
glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686 : The GNU libc libraries
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Provides    : ld-linux.so.2



glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.1.i686 : The GNU libc libraries
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Provides    : ld-linux.so.2
```

Then you can run:

```
yum install glibc-2.17-105.el7.i686 -y
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you said something about what to do with the output of that.

Comment: It should be there now

Comment: This is a very useful command also yum groupinstall "Compatibility libraries"

Comment: The advice to use **yum provides** here is much more valuable than direct rpm links which usually follow similar questions.

Comment: yum provides ld-linux.so.2
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror1.cl.netactuate.com
 * extras: mirror1.cl.netactuate.com
 * updates: mirror1.cl.netactuate.com
No matches found